# Access list from a function

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have created a function which returns a list

```
def GetAddressContainer(obj,obj1):

     mylist = list()
     for i in test['adresss']:
         addresscotainer = i[id]

   return mylist(addresscontainer)
```

When i call the function -

```
 UkContainer = GetAddressContainer(Postcode,Country)
```

i get the following error message:

```
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python
```

Any ideas why i am getting this error and what i would have to update?

Comment: `return mylist` returns a list... `mylist(addresscontainer)` tries to call a list, and lists are not callable

Comment: Also, you never use `Postcode,Country`, so why pass those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issues

---

The line `mylist = list()` basically creates an empty list which you can use to store any values. In the code `mylist` is being called (using `(...)`) which does not make sense in python since `mylist` is not a function.

Another issue with the code is that the value of `addresscontainer` is never being inserted into `mylist`.

#### Possible Solutions

---

So, as per your problem, either of the following solutions can be used:

- Append `addresscontainer` into `mylist` iteratively within the for loop:

  ```
  for i in test['adress']:
      addresscontainer = i[id]
      mylist.append(addresscontainer)         # Inserts the value at the end of list

  return mylist                               # Returns the list
  ```
- **[RECOMMENDED]** Use list comprehension:

  ```
  def GetAddressContainer(...):
      return [i[id] for i in test['adress']]  # Build list using "List Comprehension"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The problems seem to be in

```
return mylist(addresscontainer)
```

You using parentheses on the list and therefore calling it as a function, that's why you get the error. Without any more code I not entirely sure what to replace it with though.

Answer (score 0):

change `mylist = list()` to `mylist = []`

it will create an empty list instead of a list object.

and you are not appending anything to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mylist(addresscontainer)` with `list(addresscontainer)` code.

Only `list` word could be a callable function because it defines a class of any list. And `mylist = list()` will be an instance of an abstract list, then, not callable.